# Pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims kong-ingress-controller

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I follow [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Kong/kubernetes-ingress-controller/master/deploy/single/all-in-one-postgres.yaml) to install kong-ingress-controller in my master node. But when I deploy postgres-0 it created volume which is pending. I using my own cloud. Here is my yaml to create persistanvolume:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: postgre-pv-volume
  namespace : kong
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/var/lib/postgresql/data"
```

When I run `kubectl describe pod postgres-0 -n kong`

Result:

```
Name:           postgres-0
Namespace:      kong
Priority:       0
Node:           <none>
Labels:         app=postgres
                controller-revision-hash=postgres-59ccf8fcf7
                statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name=postgres-0
Annotations:    <none>
Status:         Pending
IP:             
IPs:            <none>
Controlled By:  StatefulSet/postgres
Containers:
  postgres:
    Image:      postgres:9.5
    Port:       5432/TCP
    Host Port:  0/TCP
    Environment:
      POSTGRES_USER:      kong
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD:  kong
      POSTGRES_DB:        kong
      PGDATA:             /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
    Mounts:
      /var/lib/postgresql/data from datadir (rw,path="pgdata")
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-g7828 (ro)
Conditions:
  Type           Status
  PodScheduled   False 
Volumes:
  datadir:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  datadir-postgres-0
    ReadOnly:   false
  default-token-g7828:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-g7828
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age        From               Message
  ----     ------            ----       ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  <unknown>  default-scheduler  pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims
  Warning  FailedScheduling  <unknown>  default-scheduler  pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims
```

Please help me. Thanks

Comment: have you created storageClassName : manual ? i think it's issue of storage class as volume is in pending state

Comment: @HarshManvar I think I havent. Can you show me how I can create storage class local?

Comment: try with removing that line

Answer (score 3):

Problem may lay in bad or none configuration of [StorageClass](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/).

**1.** Firstly you have to ensure that you have storageclass called manual.

```
$ kubectl get storageclass
```

The name of a StorageClass object is significant, and is how users can request a particular class.

**2.** To create StorageClass you have to define configuration file, here is example:

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: manual
provisioner: xxx
reclaimPolicy: Retain
allowVolumeExpansion: true
mountOptions:
  - debug
volumeBindingMode: Immediate
```

Storage classes have a [provisioner](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/#provisioner) that determines what volume plugin is used for provisioning PVs. This field must be specified (xxx).

Take note on such definition:

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: local-storage
provisioner: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
```

[Local volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/#local)  do not currently support dynamic provisioning, however a StorageClass should still be created to delay volume binding until pod scheduling. This is specified by the WaitForFirstConsumer volume binding mode.

Delaying volume binding allows the scheduler to consider all of a pod’s scheduling constraints when choosing an appropriate PersistentVolume for a PersistentVolumeClaim.

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Does it help ? Would you consider upvote/accept it, it will be useful for community.